# How to avoid HTTP Status 415 when sending ajax request to the server?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json

I have an `AJAX` call that should return `JSON` document

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/x',
        type: 'GET',
        data: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            // code omitted
        }
    });
}
```

My server side is very simple.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/x", method = GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<Employee> get() {
    return employeeService.getEmployees();
}
```

But my request can't even get to the controller. The error is:

```
HTTP Status 415 - The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you check your configuration and specify media types that are supported?

Comment: What do you mean? My pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

add `@Consumes("text/html")` before your code in server side,

```
@Consumes("text/html")
@RequestMapping(value = "/x", method = GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<Employee> get() {
    return employeeService.getEmployees();
}
```